# How to get active/context.area in the modal operator?

Tags: python

I want the `context.area` in the modal operator when I change the workspaces to e.g. Shading workspace.

Currently, when I change the workspace I get `None` when I `print(context.area)`

[image]

```
import bpy
import gpu
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader


class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Move an object with the mouse, example"""
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def draw_callback(self):
        vertices = (
            (100, 100), (300, 100),
            (100, 200), (300, 200))

        indices = (
            (0, 1, 2), (2, 1, 3))

        shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('UNIFORM_COLOR')
        batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)

        shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
        batch.draw(shader)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.handler = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(self.draw_callback, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        print(context.area)

        if event.type in {"ESC", "RIGHTMOUSE"}:
            bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handler, 'WINDOW')
            context.area.tag_redraw()
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(ModalOperator.bl_idname, text=ModalOperator.bl_label)


# Register and add to the "view" menu (required to also use F3 search "Simple Modal Operator" for quick access).
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I also want a solution too. When a operator running, change workspace also make the `event.mouse_region_x` not usable.

Comment: Is there any way to restart the modal operator `if context.area is None`?

Comment: I tried but failed before. The `context, event` of restarted modal still cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

It was a subject I was curious about a lot when I started coding in Blender.

Unfortunately, such a thing is not possible in blender.

Blender didn't have a direct event handler specifically for workspace changes.
However, I recommend using a timer rather than doing this with a gpu coding.

It also writes to the console in the following piece of code.

The code is:

```
import bpy

class CheckWorkspaceOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Check Current Workspace"""
    bl_idname = "object.check_workspace"
    bl_label = "Check Workspace"

    _timer = None
    _previous_workspace = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            current_workspace = context.workspace
            if current_workspace is not None:
                workspace_name = current_workspace.name
                if workspace_name != self._previous_workspace:
                    print(f"Current Workspace Name: {workspace_name}")
                    self._previous_workspace = workspace_name
            else:
                print("No active workspace found")

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            return self.cancel(context)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        current_workspace = context.workspace
        if current_workspace is not None:
            workspace_name = current_workspace.name
            print(f"Current Workspace Name: {workspace_name}")
            self._previous_workspace = workspace_name
        else:
            print("No active workspace found")
            self._previous_workspace = None

        self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(1.0, window=context.window)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        if self._timer:
            context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        return {'CANCELLED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(CheckWorkspaceOperator.bl_idname, text=CheckWorkspaceOperator.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CheckWorkspaceOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CheckWorkspaceOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you want, you can also write this in the info field. Instead of print:

`self.report({'INFO'}, f"Current Workspace Name: {workspace_name}")`